# Popups - jQuery Mobile, Backbone.js and Require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I am using jQuery Mobile, Backbone.js and Require.js with Phonegap. I followed the method provided in the [jQuery Mobile documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/backbone-requirejs/). Since backbone takes over the routing anything that relies on anchors to be triggered is not working. For example, if I want to call a popup I need to call it dynamically since popups are triggered by adding the element id.

Any ideas or suggestions that does not involve individually calling each widget? I thought about listening to on click events but I don't want to add another listener if I don't need to.

Answer (score -1):

```
events: {
   'click #triggerPopup': 'openPopUp'
},

openPopUp: function(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   $('#modalSuccessTrigger').popup('open')
}
```

Calling the popup programmatically works.